# Website hacked and redirected with 1700 spam backlinks

Tags: redirects, backlinks, spam

Ok, so here is the deal. I have a client that got a website with me. But before he did one day he was hacked and his website had about 120 links and in the middle of december his site all the sudden had 1700 links. When you would put in his company name in google search his site would come up but when you click it in google search it would take you to Dr. Dre Headphones website. Now he has 1700 links that we see are crap links. I understand the "disavow" process but he doesn't have that kind of money to pay me to go and send a email to all the links and ask them to remove the link. He was in really good standing on google local but not since this happened. There has to be something that can be done within reason. He did nothing to deserve this and he is just a small Biz man. Please Help.

[image]

Comment: Sorry but there is a large number of questions and answers already on Pro Webmasters regarding recovering from backlink spam and hacks. To avoid future disappointment please ensure you search the site first, also avoid questions being to specific on circumstances that are unlikely to help others.

Comment: Just use disavow tool, who cares if the headphones sites take them down or not. Dont even waste time contacting them, let him do that on his own time later. Also if the site was forwarding, i would look in htaccess man